# sql row_number() vs select row_number() to get data

Tags: sql, sql-server, rowcount, partition-by

i have the following table

```
Prod_id   Units sold
 1,       100 
 2,       95 
 3,       84 
 4,       95 
 5,       100
```

I want to know why the first query gives proper row counts while the 2nd one returns only 1's

```
select 
 (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by amount order by id)) 
from Products 


select *, 
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by amount order by id) a )  
from Products
```

Results are here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dfd59/11

I want to use this to apply 100, 100 1st and 5th 
rows and 95, 95 to the 2nd and 4th rows within this query 
without using a `with` statement.
Please let me know if there is a way

Comment: instead of writing as a subquery, write it as an expression

Comment: Could you share an example?

Comment: `select *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by amount order by id) a  
from Products `

Comment: Use your first query, take the row_Number window function out of those parenthesis, they do nothing but add noise. Then add the other columns you want.

Comment: In your first query, Row_Number() is evaluated as an expression; in your second it is part of a subquery that gets executed once per each row in Products. Since the subquery only has one row each time it's executed, it will always return 1

Comment: I'm upvoting because I clearly have not had to explain what happens in this situation, so you have an interesting question.  I hope my explanation makes some sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a subquery without a `from` clause is a waste of a subquery.  It doesn't do anything desirable.

Just call the function directly.

Note:  This advice applies to *any* expression in a subquery, not only `row_number()`.

Why does your subquery return only "1"s?  That reason is rather subtle to explain.  But, imagine that the subquery were written as:

```
select *, 
       (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by amount order by id) a
        from dual)
```

This is, in fact, how the query could or would be written in several SQL databases.  `dual` is a table with exactly one row.  That little fact emphasizes what is happening.  The subquery is referring to *one row at a time*.  Hence, the `row_number()` that you are getting refers only to partitioning by that row.  Voila!  You only get "1".

I realize that it might help if you considered the subquery as:

```
select *, 
       (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by amount order by id) a
        from (select products.amount, products.id) p
       )
```

This emphasizes that the `row_number()` is being applied over the result set of the sub-select.  That sub-select -- by definition -- has only one row, which results in the "1" being returned.